# how can i draw implicit function with sin, cos function and find root in pyhton?

Tags: python, function, implicit

i have a function like this

cos(x) - sin(y) + 0.2 = 0

i want to draw this function in plt.plot and find root (x,y) when function = 0
and this is my code

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np
   
def func_2(x):
    return np.cos(x[0])-np.sin(x[1])+0.2

result = optimize.root(func_2, [1])
```

and i got error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-366-6d13d246d69c> in <module>
     14 
     15 result = optimize.root(func_1, [1])
---> 16 result1 = optimize.root(func_2, [1])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_root.py in root(fun, x0, args, method, jac, tol, callback, options)
    185 
    186     if meth == 'hybr':
--> 187         sol = _root_hybr(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, **options)
    188     elif meth == 'lm':
    189         sol = _root_leastsq(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, **options)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
    211     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    212         args = (args,)
--> 213     shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
    214     if epsfcn is None:
    215         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

<ipython-input-366-6d13d246d69c> in func_2(x)
     11 
     12 def func_2(x):
---> 13     return np.cos(x[0])-np.sin(x[1])+0.2
     14 
     15 result = optimize.root(func_1, [1])
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: ```result = optimize.root(func_2, [1])``` Since you're passing ```[1]``` as an argument, ```np.sin(x[1])``` will give an index error

Comment: then how  can i fix it?

Comment: You'll need to pass two parameters in the list, like ```[value1, value2]```